# Strategy to develop a complex react component step by step

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, frontend, user-experience

Lately I was asked what could be the best ordered strategy to develop a complex react component starting with a ticket with criteria and also a screen design which represents the Interface.

Let's say we have an overwiev page of a given set of data. This involves pulling the data from an API for now without manipulating it. The components will view the given data in human readable tables and text.

For the react part: Fetching and storing data and frontend could be done via either react-query or redux. The api-fetch functionality already exists.

Routing and reaching the page is given.

- Should one start with a plain dom structure?
- Should one start with the api-call?
- Should one start developing all the single Components which end up being used in the overwiev page?
- What is your approach to a task with the given information?

This question could also match Vue or other frontend frameworks but came up when using React.